# Getting started working with large projects

Tags: javascript, windows

This may be a fools errand, asking this question, since it is such a broad subject. But I'm a little overwhelmed as a jr. Developer trying to figure out where to start.

So far in my few month long career, I've been working with smaller projects, small ui modifications to existing projects. Now I'm being tasked with merging, or making 3 different projects compatible with one another, much larger than anything I've even seen, let alone worked with.

The code is complex, and a lot of it is pretty advanced. This is looking like it might be a few month long ordeal. Is there any advice you all have as far as learning other code bases? Understanding their architecture/functionality?

Unfortunately my NDA precludes me from giving out any specifics about the project to perhaps get more information, and I'm the most senior person on this team. Any and all advice you can give me about where to start learning a large code base, with lots of functionality would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is indeed too generic to be addressed here, maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ could clear some of your issues in tackling new projects or specific technologies.

If you have specific questions regarding issues you find with compatibility between the technologies you have to integrate then we might be able to help.

One generic piece of advice I would give anyone tackling a new task is to take your time to first understand the requirements and the projects you are going to work on.

Another piece of advice would be to ask for a more senior programmer help you with the task, even if he can not actually work on the project he could still guide some of your decisions. It's always good to have a someone to bounce your ideas on.

Also considering that you are the most senior in the team, remember to consult with your colleagues.

Every project is different though and there's no specific solution we could give you to help you complete such a generic task.